# Relation between Frobenius Norm and Maximum of a Singular value of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have been reading about normalizing a square matrix.

I found two different notions of norm of a matrix. One is Frobenius norm and other is maximum of singular value of matrix.

Frobenius Norm(A) = $\sqrt{Tr(A^{\dagger}A)}$

Norm(A)= $Max[\sqrt{eigenvalue(A^{\dagger}A)}]$

($\dagger$ represents transpose conjugate of matrix A)

Are they same as I cannot see them to be same. What is the difference and why ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^†$. Then what remains is
$$
\|A\|_F=\sqrt{tr(\Sigma^2)}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^r\sigma_i^2}
$$
while as you said $\|A\|_{2,op}=\max_{k=1,..,r}\sigma_k$.

Comment: Yes but are they same or different ? I cannot make it out.

Comment: They are equivalent norms on the tuple of singular values, but they are not the same.

Comment: What dpes it mean tuple of singular values, sorry I am not a mathematician

Comment: It means the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $\Sigma$ as a vector. $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices or parts of such. The actual matrix dimensions in the decomposition can be chosen so that $U,V$ are quadratic and $\Sigma$ is rectangular, or in the smaller version so that $\Sigma$ is quadratic and minimal, and $U,V$ are then correspondingly rectangular.